# MYSQL select values from two tables with the particular condition

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. One is **query** Table which contains all types of queries and one is **query_insert** which contains only the query insertion record.
Like below:

```
    **query**            **query_insert**
    1 query_id           1 id
    2 query_cons         2 query_id
    3 title              3 *insert_date*
    4 name               4 insert_time
    5.............
    ...........
    .....
    9 *current_status*
    10 return_date
```

I want to select all those queries from query which are having current_status as fresh and  insert_date is today(which is in query_insert).

I tried this but not working.

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT query_insert.*, query.* 
                      FROM query_insert,query 
                      WHERE query_insert.insert_date=$today && 
                            query.current_status='Fresh' ");
```

In this query $today is variable contains date of today.

Please help me out.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join your two tables on the attribute that links them, `query_id`.
You can try something like this:

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT query_insert.*, query.* 
                      FROM query_insert 
                          LEFT JOIN query 
                                   ON query.query_id = query_insert.query_id
                      WHERE query_insert.insert_date=$today && 
                            query.current_status='Fresh' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT * FROM query q
INNER JOIN query_insert qi ON q.query_id = qi.query_id
WHERE insert_date = CURRENT_DATE()
AND current_status = 'Fresh'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM query q
JOIN query_insert i
ON q.id = i.query_id
WHERE q.current_status = 'Fresh'
AND i.insert_date = now()
```

Or if you have more rows in query_insert about the same query:

```
SELECT *
FROM query q
WHERE EXISTS(
   SELECT 'insert'
   FROM query_insert i
   WHERE q.id = i.query_id
   AND i.insert_date = now()
)
AND q.current_status = 'Fresh'
```

Answer (score 0):

please change your query as following :

```
SELECT query_insert.*, query.* 
FROM query_insert,query 
WHERE query_insert.insert_date = $today 
AND query.current_status='Fresh' 
AND query.query_id = query_insert.query_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove one of the "&& query.current_status='Fresh' " to check if that is really the date clause that isn't working.

once you verified that check that your variable and your column are both date and not datetime. if the column is datetime then instead of making it =$today  make it a range, thus insert_date>= $today and insert_date <= tomorrow<